# Why microservice accepts request event though it is down in eureka server registry?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have few microservices which is registered to Eureka Server(http://localhost:10100)

I am removing instance from eureka server using below REST API

Ref : https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations

1) Remove instance from eureka server (DELETE) (It remove instance but again re-register..)

http://localhost:10100/eureka/apps/MICRO-SERVICE-1/localhost:micro-service-1:10501

2) Update status of service to DOWN/OUT_OF_SERVICE

http://localhost:10100/eureka/apps/MICRO-SERVICE-1/localhost:micro-service-1:10501/status?value=DOWN

So even when micro-service-1 status is set to DOWN/OUT_OF_SERVICE I am able to send request to micro-service-1 (http://localhost:10501/MyService/hello)

Instead it should be unavailable but it accepting request an giving response.

So, Why microservice accepts request event though it's status is down in eureka server registry ?

Eureka Server application.yml file

```
server:
  port: 10100
  address: localhost
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:10100/eureka/
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: true
    wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 0
```

Eureka Client (micro-service-1) application.yml file

```
server:
  port: 10501
  address: localhost
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:10100/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    prefer-ip-address: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Your service has no built-in way of interpreting that you've taken it down in Eureka so calling your service by directly hitting its port will always work.

To make use of the directory's knowledge of server status and multiple instances of servers you need to call your service from an API such as [ribbon](https://spring.io/guides/gs/client-side-load-balancing/) that can construct a software load balancer from the directory. Alternatively make your calls through the [Zuul API proxy](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html) which is essentially just a microservice built around ribbon internally.

In all these cases remember that the cloud microservices are *eventually consistent*. That is, changes you make may not be instantly available and will take time to propagate out to the running services.